# Probability question, why is symmetry required between P(A1) and P(A2)?

Tags: probability

Really sorry if it's a stupid question.
This is an early example from "An Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and it's Applications" by Richard J. Larsen.

The textbook claims (from my understanding) that the probability of A1 (first card is lower in rank) and A2(first card is higher in rank) to be the same. But I do not understand how that can be the case? Let's say I draw an ace (numerical value of 1) wouldn't P(A2) be zero since the second ace can only ever trump or equal the first draw?

I am not quite sure what I am missing.

[image: A probability problem]

Comment: Think in this way, when you draw an ace first, what would be the event (A1 or A2)? Keep it in mind that A1 is an event that "the first card is lower in rank" and A2 "the first card is higher in rank".

Comment: @user115350 Wouldn't it be an event that doesn't figure in the sample space since all A(i)s imply two cards were drawn? (Thank you for your answer btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A_1) = P(A_2)$ initially, before you gain information about the cards. Once you look at the first card, we're in the realm of conditional probability; for example, if $B$ is the event "the first card is an ace" then you are right that $P(A_2 \mid B) = 0$.

To put it differently: out of the $52 \cdot 51$ total outcomes (hands of two cards drawn without replacement), an equal number are in $A_1$ (hands of two cards where the first is lower in rank) and in $A_2$ (hands of two cards where the first is higher in rank). It is no problem that $A_2$ does not contain any outcomes where the first card is an ace; after all, $A_1$ does not contain any outcomes where the second card is an ace.

Comment: First thanks a lot for the answer! I see. Ok I think it makes sense, then I have to wonder is there a general way (something to look out for) that allows one to know that by symmetry two probabilities should be the same?

Comment: There are a few ways to look at it, some more formal than others. The way I'd put it here: for every outcome in $A_1$, you can swap the two cards to get an outcome in $A_2$, and vice versa. This is a bijection telling us that $|A_1| = |A_2|$; dividing by $|S|$, we get that the probabilities are also the same. Such a bijective argument is a general strategy to identify symmetries.

Comment: Oooh I see! Thanks again, this makes perfect sense. :D

Comment: Welcome to this site! [Accepting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) ✔ and upvoting ▲ answers are good ways to say thanks; these actions signal resolution, prevent the page from being bumped, score points, and influence the site's search results, cleanup activities, and other behind-the-scenes processes.